# Jackson still return Json value of lazy fetched field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I have a `Student` class with a `OnetoOne` relationship.

```java
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
    private StudentStatus statusID;
```

This is the controller:

```java
public Page<StudentDTO> getAllStudents(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
                             @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size,
                             @RequestParam(name = "filter", required = false) String fieldName,
                             @RequestParam(name = "value", required = false) String fieldValue) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        Specification<Student> spec = StudentSpecification.hasFieldWithValueLike(fieldName,fieldValue);
        return studentService.getStudents(spec, pageable);}
```

Service:

```java
public Page<StudentDTO> getStudents(Specification<Student> spec, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Student> studentPage = studentRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
    return studentPage.map(student -> studentMapper.toDTO(student));}
```

I know that my lazy fetch is successful because it returns an extra field: `hibernateLazyInitializer`.

From my understanding, the returned json from a `GET` will not have any data for the lazy fetched field `StudentStatus`, but the response still has all the value of `StudentStatus`.

I also benchmark my API using JMeter for 10000 requests. And it seems like without lazy fetch it's actually faster by 2ms on average.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how Hibernate lazy loading works. The `StudentStatus` will not be fetched with the `findAll` method. It will be only substituted with a proxy. However in the next line your mapper access the getters of the `statusID` field causing Hibernate to fetch the `StudentStatus` entity with an additional select statement. This will of course take some additional time.

If you don't need the `StudentStatus` in your `StudentDTO` you can remove it from the mapper.